# Using a PHP Socket Server for AS3 on Wamp: Sandbox Violation

Tags: php, actionscript-3, wamp, sandbox, serversocket

I know this has been touched on a lot, however, despite it all, I just don't get it. If you guys could bear with me :(

So, I've got this Code:

```
import flash.net.*;
import fl.controls.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.DataEvent;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;

var mySocket = new XMLSocket();
trace(Security.sandboxType)
pushMsg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, realsedButton);
//mySocket.connect("192.124.5.2",9999);
mySocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, xmlsocket);
mySocket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, xmlsocket);
mySocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, xmlsocket);
mySocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler);
mySocket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityHandler);   

msgArea.htmlText = "Started!";
connectToServer();
function connectToServer()
{
    msgArea.htmlText += "Inside connect To Server";
    mySocket.connect("localhost",9999);
}

function securityHandler(evt: SecurityErrorEvent)
{
    msgArea.htmlText += "SecurityError";
}

function dataHandler(evt:DataEvent)
{
    trace("Inside dataHandler")
    var xml = XML(evt.target.data);
    msgArea.htmlText += xml;
}


function xmlsocket(Event)
{
    msgArea.htmlText += "inside xmlSocket";
    switch(Event.type)
    {
        case 'ioError':
            msgArea.htmlText += "Inside dataHandler";
            msgArea.htmlText += "<b>Server connection failed!</b>";
            break;

        case 'connect':
            msgArea.htmlText +="Inside Connect";
            msgArea.htmlText += "<b>Server connection establed!</b>";
            break;

        case 'close':
            msgArea.htmlText +="Inside Close";
            msgArea.htmlText += "<b>Server connection lost</b>";
            break;
    }
}
function msgGO() 
{
    msgArea.htmlText +="Inside msgGO";
    if (inputMsg.htmlText != "") 
    {
        msgArea.htmlText +="Inside msgGo2";
        mySocket.send(inputMsg.htmlText+"\n");
        inputMsg.htmlText = "";
    }
}

function realsedButton(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    msgArea.htmlText +="Inside ReleasedButton";
    msgGO();
}
```

I've done a LOT of testing, I'll try and sum it all up neatly.

**If run from Flash directly** (ctrl+enter) and the **socket server is OFFLINE** and the **permissions is set to Network** AND the line mySocket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityHandler) is **COMMENTED OUT**

The output is as Followed:

- Started!
- Inside Connect to Server
- Inside xmlsocket
- Inside dataHandler
- Server Connection Failed

Error #2044 unhandled security error.txt = error #2048 security sandbox violation file ///G|/flash%20Stuff/socketClientNetwork.swf cannot load data from localhost:9999 at socketClientNetwork_fla::maintimeline/frame 1{}

If **run from the SWF** and the **socket server is OFFLINE** and the **permission is set to Network** AND the line (from above) is **NOT commented out**
The output is as follows:

- Started!

  Inside Connect to Server

  Security Error

If run from **Flash directly** (ctrl+enter) and the **socket server is OFFLINE** and the permissions is set to **Local** AND the line mySocket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityHandler) is **COMMENTED OUT**

The output is as follows:

- Started!
- Inside Conenct to Server
- Inside xmlsocket
- Inside datahandeler
- Server Connection Failed

Error #2044 unhandled security error.txt = error #2048 security sandbox violation file ///G|/flash%20Stuff/socketClientLocal.swf cannot load data from localhost:9999 at socketClientLocal_fla::maintimeline/frame 1{}

If run from the **SWF** and the socket server and the socket server is **OFFLINE** and the permissions is set to **Local** AND the line (as above) is **NOT commented**

- Started!
- Inside Connect to Server
- Security Error

SWF :: Online :: Local :: Commented

- Started!
- Inside Connect to Server
- Security Error

FLA :: Online :: Local :: Uncommented

- Started!
- Inside Connect to Server
- Inside xmlsocket
- Inside connect to Server
- Connection Established

SWF::Online::Network::Commented

- Started!
- Inside Connect to Server
- Security Error

FLA::Online::Network::Uncommented

- Started!
- Inside connect to server
- Inside xml socket
- Inside connect
- Server Connection Established

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to move the swf on filesystem to your local web server's document root folder or a subfolder of it and then type in browser address bar:

```
http://localhost/socketClientLocal.swf
```

instead of

```
file:///G|/flash%20Stuff/socketClientLocal.swf
```

Additionally you'll have to create a so called 'socket policy file' named `crossdomain.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="localhost" toports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

On `connect()` Flash Player first tries to load this file. If it fails to load or the settings restrict access, flash player triggers the security error you encountered too.

Flash Player tries to load the `crossdomain.xml` in the following order:

- port 843 of the server you passed to `connect()` (localhost:843 in your case)
- the server:port you passed to `connect()` (localhost:9999 in your case)

Now you have two options:

- Create an additional server on port 843 that just serves the crossdomain.xml
- Serve the crossdomain.xml by your own server

You'll find many useful information [here](http://www.lightsphere.com/dev/articles/flash_socket_policy.html). Also you can find ready-to-use socket policy server software (for port 843) across the web. e.g. [mod_socket_policy_server](http://socketpolicyserver.com/) for Apache. Tip: Google for 'socket policy server'

Good Luck!

Comment: Ok moved the socketClientLocal.swf to E:/wamp/www/socketClientLocal.swf and ran it and got: Started! Inside connect to Server Security Error

Comment: did you set the allowNetworking attribute in your <object> and <embed> tag properly?

Comment: Ok moved the socketClientLocal.swf to E:/wamp/www/socketClientLocal.swf and ran it SWF :: Online :: Local :: Uncommented and got: Started! Inside connect to Server Security Error   , Also tried E:/wamp/www/SocketClientNetwork.swf and ran it SWF :: Online :: Network :: Uncommented with same result

Comment: Herma no idea >.< like on the php socket?

Comment: That post up there is the entire FLA file, I can post the php socket server as well if needed?

Comment: no,not needed. -> 'allowNetworking' : in the HTML (you should google this). You'll have to use `http://localhost/SocketClientNetwork.swf` as address in browser

Comment: We arn't using an HTML, we are using wamp for mysql, php, and apache. Joomla for the website itself, and using an SWF wrapper to integrate the swf onto the site

Comment: But you can investigate the rendered page in browser. Can you post the <object> tag and its contents?

Comment: OK, when I go to localhost/SocketClientNetwork.swf and inspect it, there is no object tag at all. However, when I go to the joomla sight and inspect, the object tag is as follows: <object>type = "application/x-shockwave-flash" data = "http://localhost/midnightA/modules/mod_swfObject/lib/socketClientNetwork.swf" width = "500" Height = "500" ID = "flashId" style = "visibiity: visible;" ><param name = "menu" value > <param name = "wmode" value = "window" > < param name = "allow script access" value = "always" > </object>

Comment: Have a Look at the updated answer and create the crossdomain.xml. What happens? does it connect now?

Comment: Do you have a Socket Policy File?